display image to html page using javascript
My intention is to display image on html page using javascript, the image is in folder and image id stored in table but nothing displayed, as shown below 
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  var id = 12
  $.get("http://localhost/myci/public/route/imageview/" + id,
    function(data, status) {
      if (data) {
        let images = $.parseJSON(data);
        images = images[0];
        imageId = images['imageId'];
        $('#mysnap').html('<img src="C:/xampp/htdocs/myci/public/uploads/' + imageId + '" height="100" width="100" alt="">');
      }
    });
});

<div id="mysnap"></div>


You want  your image to be loaded via http://localhost/, not C:/xampp/htdocs/...

You appear to be running the page on a local webserver (given the request to localhost) yet you are trying to load the image file from your C: drive, which will be inaccessible. You need to put the image within the file storage available to the webserver, then use a relative path to it, from the current HTML page.

Web browsers don't typically allow you to read from the file system on a website.
Since you are already running a local web server, you can access the uploads/ directory by it's web URI instead of the absolute file path on your system.
Change C:/xampp/htdocs to http://localhost in the image URL.
$('#mysnap').html('<img src="http://localhost/myci/public/uploads/' + imageId + '" height="100" width="100" alt="">');

If you can get the relative path, that will be better. It depends on the location of your HTML document in the file tree.
<img src="/myci/public/uploads/' + imageId + '">' <!-- or -->
<img src="public/uploads/' + imageId + '">' <!-- or -->
<img src="../uploads/' + imageId + '">'

Alternatively you, you can write the jQuery code like this, which may make it a little more obvious how you are defining your <img> element.
$('<img>')
  .attr('src', "http://localhost/myci/public/uploads/" + imageId)
  .attr('width', 100)
  .attr('height', 100)
  .attr('alt', "")
  .appendTo('#mysnap')

